# zsh: command not found after npm install in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, npm

I have installed up to date version of node using:

```
curl -s -O https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_5.7.1-1nodesource1~trusty1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install rlwrap
sudo dpkg -i nodejs_5.7.1-1nodesource1~trusty1_amd64.deb
```

There after I installed yo using

```
 npm install -g yo
```

But when I try it out, I get an error that says:

```
zsh: command not found
```

With `echo $PATH`,

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

How can I get this working ? I am very new to Ubuntu and pretty clueless about it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the

```
zsh: command not found
```

issue for the npm libraries by setting the path in ~/.zshrc

Setting the following path in ~/.zshrc solved my issue

```
echo 'export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to change `.npm-global` to `.npm-packages`

Answer (score 1):

This script works for me. You have to add it at the end of `~/.zshrc`.

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.nvm" ]; then
  # export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
  export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

  # This loads nvm bash_completion
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who used `n` to install a specific node version and were using **Ubuntu's** bash terminal then installed `zsh` you can add the following on the top of your `~/.zshrc`

```
export N_PREFIX="$HOME/n"; [[ :$PATH: == *":$N_PREFIX/bin:"* ]] || PATH+=":$N_PREFIX/bin"  # Added by n-install (see http://git.io/n-install-repo).
```

After that run `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score -1):

zsh is a alernative to your bash shell.

You installed yeoman for node. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/yo)

To install zsh you can do so like this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install zsh
```

and then type `zsh` to get started with zsh.

If you like zsh you should look into oh-my-zsh for some nice terminal themes and plugins.

http://ohmyz.sh/